# Bigcartel - availability as number instead of bar?

Tags: bigcartel

This is likely a very simple question that I am brainfarting on - Is there a way to have my shop with the Luna theme show an actual numerical quantity available rather than the simple bars?

I'm certain I have seen this done somewhere but I can't find an example of the code anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To show the quantity in your inventory bar area, head to Customize Design > Advanced > CSS and add this at the very bottom:

```
#product_inventory .bar span em {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I have changed the following in the Luna theme.css file to provide this functionality as the first answer no longer works.
Edit the css to replace display: none with display: block

```
.inventory-bars .inventory-label {
  color: {{ theme.secondary_text_color }};
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -16px;
}
```

[Numerical quality shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYOhp.png)

[bigcartel]